# Why does scanf not working with regex and dynamic allocation

Tags: c, scanf, dynamic-allocation

I'm trying to use scanf with a char pointer to store a string. In case of ENTER key stroke, I want it to be catched. I know I could use fgets but I'm curious to know if it's possible so I managed to write the following code:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int main(void)
{
    char *string = NULL;

    printf("Type anything : ");

    scanf("%*[^\n]%10[^\n]ms", string);

    printf("Your input : %s\n", string);

    free(string);

    return EXIT_SUCCESS;
}
```

But doesn't seems to work well. Here's the output :

```
Type anything : 123
Your input : (null)
Type anything : 
Your input : (null)
```

How can I make my program to display the string correctly ?

Comment: 1) Tehere is no regex in your code. `scanf` does not support them. 2) Please learn how memory allocaltion works in C. Your code shows major missconception. 3) Your code invokes _undefined behaviour_ (serach for it!)

Comment: `scanf("%*[^\n]%10[^\n]ms", string);` --> `scanf("%m[^\n]%*c", &string);` with glibc.

Comment: @BLUEPIXY Care to elaborate what you mean?

Comment: The null string remains null. You need to preallocate the string yourself.

Comment: @Kusalananda see [Example](http://linux.die.net/man/3/sscanf). glibc supports the `m`. OP  knows `m` but wrong usage.

Comment: @BLUEPIXY Tho OP does not mention glibc. He does, however, use `scanf()` with a `NULL` value (having failed to allocate `string`). He also frees an unallocated pointer.

Comment: @BLUEPIXY thanks it worked that way. Could you explain why am I seing %*c but the resultat gives me a nice text (not that it bothers me) ?

Comment: @Kusalananda Thanks a lot for the link. Gaves me some intel. Should have  scrolled a little bit more. Next time i'll do.

Comment: `%*c` : It will consume the newline. (Since `[^\n]` does not accept the newline)

Answer (score 1):

The first thing you need to know before I explain your issue is that **`%[^\n]` will fail if the first character to be read is a `\n`**.

Now lets analyze what `scanf("%*[^\n]%10[^\n]ms", string);` means:

1. `%*[^\n]` scans everything until a newline character, but doesn't scan in the final `\n`.
2. `%10[^\n]ms` doesn't really do what you think it does:

   - Remember! `%s` and `%[` are two *different* format specifiers! The trailing `s` is *not* part of the `%[` specifier.
   - You got the `m` at the wrong position.

   Correcting these, it should be `%10m[^\n]` which scans everything until a newline character or a maximum of 10 characters, whichever happens first, and also allocates enough memory to hold this string.

Another bug is that `m` expects a `char**`, not a `char*` and so, you should be supplying `&string` and not just `string`.

Now, lets execute your `scanf` (after correcting the above mistakes)!

1. Execution reaches the `scanf` and `scanf` waits for input.
2. You type `123\n`.
3. `%*[^\n]` scans and discards the `123`, sees the `\n`, and stops scanning, not consuming the `\n`.
4. `%10m[^\n]` sees the `\n` and **fails** for the reason given in the first sentence of my answer.
5. `scanf` returns 0 (since nothing was scanned and assigned successfully) and `scanf` completes execution.
6. `printf` prints `(null)` since `string` is still `NULL`.

Ok, so we now saw what went wrong. The real question is, why do you have `%*[^\n]` at the start of `scanf` for this small program? Remove it and everything will work as expected!

---

Suggestions:

1. Add `scanf("%*[^\n]"); getchar();` after the `scanf` so that the rest of the input (if any) along with the final `\n` gets popped out of the `stdin` and future reads will not be problematic.
2. Check the return value of `scanf` to see if it was successful or not. RTFM to know what it returns.

---

## Fixed code <sup><sub>(Untested)</sub></sup>

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int main(void)
{
    char *string = NULL;

    printf("Type anything : ");

    if(scanf("%10m[^\n]", &string) != 1)
    {
        fputs("Uh, oh! `scanf` failed! Exiting...\n", stderr);
        return EXIT_FAILURE;
    }
    scanf("%*[^\n]");
    getchar();

    printf("Your input : %s\n", string);

    free(string);

    return EXIT_SUCCESS;
}
```

---

<sup>This answer assumes that your implementation supports the `m` format specifier</sup>

Comment: Thanks, it worked. What would you suggest if I ever wanted to manage the case "user type enter key right away" ?

Comment: Good question. You could use `if(scanf("%10m[^\n]", &string) != 1){ if(getchar() == '\n'){ string = malloc(2); if(!string) { fputs("Uh, oh! \`malloc\` failed! Exiting...\n", stderr);
        return EXIT_FAILURE; } strcpy(string, " "); } else { fputs("Uh, oh! \`scanf\` failed! Exiting...\n", stderr);
        return EXIT_FAILURE; }  else if(string != NULL){ scanf("%*[^\n]"); getchar(); } else { puts("EOF, exiting..."); return EOF; }`. Note: You need `string.h` for `strcpy`.

Comment: Warning: Untested Code ↑

Answer (score 0):

The `[` format specifier (conversion, really) for `scanf()` specifies a character range of accepted (or, if it starts with `[^`, rejected) characters. It is not a regular expression.

You need to either declare `string` as a fixed-length array, or use `malloc()` to allocate memory for it.

The following modified version uses a fixed-length string of 99 characters plus a string terminating `\0` (i.e. 100 `char` long):

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int main(void)
{
        char string[100];

        printf("Type anything : ");

        scanf("%99s", string);

        printf("Your input : %s\n", string);

        return EXIT_SUCCESS;
}
```

The following variation of the code uses a dynamic array for doing the same thing:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int main(void)
{
        char *string;

        string = malloc(100);

        if (string == NULL) {
                puts("Something went wrong");
                abort();
        }

        printf("Type anything : ");

        scanf("%99s", string);

        printf("Your input : %s\n", string);

        free(string);

        return EXIT_SUCCESS;
}
```

To use regular expressions in C un a Unix system, look up the [`regcomp()`](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/009695399/functions/regcomp.html) function declared in the `regex.h` header.

Comment: `"%s.99"` --> `"%99[^\n]"` (or `"%99s"`)

Comment: @BLUEPIXY Thanks, `%s.99` should be `%.99s` (fixed).  `%99s` would allow the allocated buffer to be overflown, while `%.99s` truncates input to 99 characters. `%99[^\n]` would have the same issue with possibly overrunning the buffer, and a newline will not be read into the string in any case.

Comment: Thanks for the answer, although it's not exactly what I was asking for. But lot's of useful informations here. I do already know about static and dynamically allocated arrays.

Comment: @Gradiuss Well, the main issue with the code was exactly that (allocation).

Comment: @BLUEPIXY Sigh, you're right. I'll fix it. Mixing up formats for `scanf()` and `printf()`...

Comment: @BLUEPIXY BTW, although slightly annoyed for being asked to "RTFM", I'm happy you pointed me to the `[` format specifier as it was unknown to me. Thanks.

Comment: There is no UB. `free(NULL)` is perfectly valid and is a no-op